# how to duplicate a mysql table along with data using phymyadmin

Tags: mysql

how to duplicate a mysql table along with data using phymyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy a table, you can just execute the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE copyname SELECT * FROM originalname
```

PHPMyAdmin also has built-in functionality to export table data to a flat file.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a create table script, export it to `.sql` file, change the `table` name, and reimport it back.

Or better, take the original table schema, construct [a create table script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825449/how-to-duplicate-a-mysql-table-along-with-data-using-phymyadmin/1825464#1825464), and run the script in phpmyadmin, that should do.